# How to create nested Navigation inside Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to get something like the following example:
[Example](https://imgur.com/9NEijaE)

When I use a nested navigation flow ([link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav)), the view would take the whole screen, but instead I want to restrict the nested view inside a container for instance.

In my case, the ideal solution would be when the user clicks on the button "create Usercard", the view with the current usercards changes to a create usercard view.

[image]

Is there a "correct" solution, or should I use a stack for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PageView.builder` with an `onPageChanged` property.